# Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator]?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data

I have used the Java based configurations. When I use the jpa repositories I get the `can not create inner bean exception of type shared entity manger creator`.

Spring contex config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.sample.proj.controller" })
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.sample.proj.domain")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ServletContextConfig {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL = "hibernate.format_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY = "hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBN2DDL_SQL = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean()
            throws Exception {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean
                .setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.sample.proj.domain" });
        entityManagerFactoryBean
                .setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);

        Properties jproperties = new Properties();
        jproperties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        jproperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL));
        jproperties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY));
        jproperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        jproperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBN2DDL_SQL));
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jproperties);
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

}
```

Webintializer:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(ServletContextConfig.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(ServletContextConfig.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet(
                "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
}
```

Repository:

```
    public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, String> {

    }
```

Service class:

```
    @Service
    @Transactional
    public class PersonService {

        @Autowired
        PersonRepository personRepository;

        public Person saveDetails(Person person) {
            // System.out.println("Service Class:Person Name:"+
            // person.getPersonName());
            System.out.println("Executed");
            return person;
        }

    }
```

Controller class:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addPerson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addperson(@RequestParam("personName") String name,
                @RequestParam("personAddress") String address, Model model) {
            System.out.println("Name:" + name);
            System.out.println("Address:" + address);
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setPersonId(1);
            person.setPersonName(name);
            person.setPersonAddress(address);
            personService.saveDetails(person);
            model.addAttribute("result", "Your record inserted successfully");

            return HOME_VIEW;
        }
```

Domain class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private Integer personId;
    private String personName;
    private String personAddress;

    //getters and setters... 

}
```

The exception stacktrace is as below:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:589)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:650)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1582)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all if you look closely at your exception trace you'll see that  `ContextLoaderListner` is actually complaining about `No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined` as the root cause for not being able to create `personRepository`.

As I dont know what exact project structure is, You can try putting bean name with `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` so that Spring can find and inject it.

i.e. Something like this :

```
@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactoryBean")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the

> @EnableJpaRepositories("some.package.ref.other.than.default")

in main Application.java file did the trick for me.

I have most of my files located in package

> com.example.cortifero

Therefore, I have written my code as such (Application.java):

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.example.cortifero.jpa.service") //notice this line
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got this solution. I made this changes in the configuration file.

It executes successfully.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.sample.proj.repo" })
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class JpaConfig {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = entityManagerFactory();
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.TRUE);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.TRUE);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.sample.proj.domain");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        factory.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }
```

Comment: would you highlight as what you changed?

Comment: very frustrating when you have the same problem but they dont actually outline the change they made.

Comment: Please outline the changes being made it's difficult to find what solved the issue.

Comment: @SabirKhan, Cris Milburn, Balu Could anyone please post was solved this error for you guys? Having the same problem but can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Instead of positing entire code, post specific code for the solution