# How to create a bean of repository class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

I'm doing unit test using spring mvc test framework.

The following is my source code:
com.exmple.main

**MyController.java**

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<Object, Object> myControllerFunction(@RequestBody final Object jsonRequest) {
        /* do something */

        return response;
    }
}
```

**MyRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<My, String> {

    @Query(value="select * from my d where (d.start_date<to_date(:date,'YYYY/DD/MM')) and (d.end_date>to_date(:date,'YYYY/DD/MM'))", nativeQuery=true)
    List<My> findByDate(@Param("date") String date);
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
public interface MyService {
    List<My> findByDate(String date);
}
```

**MyServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service

public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    @Autowired
    MyRepository destRepo;

    @Override
    public List<My> findByDate(String date) {
        List<My> listDest = destRepo.findByDate(date);

        return listDest;
    }
}
```

com.example.test

**MyControllerTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={TestConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyControllerTest {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        // this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void listAllMy() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

**TestConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyService myService() {
        // set properties, etc.
        return new MyServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

When I run test, the following error is displayed
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

I know the exception occurred because MyService didn't find any bean of MyRepository.
But I don't know how to create a bean of repository.
Please teach me how to create a bean of repository class using Java (not xml).

Comment: Have you import Spring JPA configuration class? How you configures JPA? Can you show the class that configures spring JPA (with hibernate)?

Comment: In my project, there is no Spring JPA configuration class, only Controller, Service, Repository and Domain class. I use spring mvc framework. Running the application is no problem, but when running the test code, the above error occurred.

Comment: Create instances and bean definitions for the repository interfaces defined for the "unit test" context by using @EnableJpaRepositories annotation.

Comment: Are you using Mockito? If so, you can list a Mockito mock as a bean in your test configuration and inject it in your test case to manipulate from your tests.

Comment: @Shaheer Can you give me an example? Thank you

Comment: @chrylis Can you give me an exmple. Thank you.

Comment: @chrylis But my repository is an interface, not a class. I can't call return Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);

Comment: If running the application has no problem. Can you try adding the Main configuration class in @ContextConfiguration of MyControllerTest, like @ContextConfiguration(classes={TestConfig.class, RootConfig.class})

Comment: Of course you can mock an interface. That's a lot of the point.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the JPA repositories in your config class, specify the package that contains the repositories as below

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
    "com.example.repository"
})
public class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyService myService() {
        // set properties, etc.
        return new DestinationServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

Edit: looks like you haven't defined entityManager, and dataSource. Refer to [a tutorial here](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-one-configuration/) and also answer to similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653391/cannot-create-inner-bean-inner-bean-of-type-org-springframework-orm-jpa-sha)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But when I add @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
    "com.example"
}), the another error occurred Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#37654521' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager';

Comment: and more an error: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653391/cannot-create-inner-bean-inner-bean-of-type-org-springframework-orm-jpa-sha